# How to combine some rows into a single row, and delete other rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, sql-delete, sql-function

I have a table like this:

```
id | invoice_id | product_id | quantity | total
1         5           10           2        100
2         5           10           1         50
3         5           11           1        200
4         5           11           1        200
```

I want to combine the rows having same product_id in an invoice by adding their quantities and total values to one of the rows and then delete the other rows in the table. So the output should be  like this

```
id | invoice_id | product_id | quantity | total
1         5           10           3        150
3         5           11           2        400
```

How can I do this? I was thinking of using an sql function that returns a list of id's having the same invoice and product and then using aggregate functions on quantity and price. Are there any simpler ways to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need an `UPDATE` statement that updates for each `invoice_id`, `product_id` combination the row with the min `id` with the totals of `quantity` and `total`:

```
UPDATE tablename t
SET quantity = s.quantity,
    total = s.total
FROM (
  SELECT MIN(id) id, SUM(quantity) quantity, SUM(total) total
  FROM tablename
  GROUP BY invoice_id, product_id
) s
WHERE s.id = t.id;
```

Then a `DELETE` statement to delete all the other ids:

```
DELETE FROM tablename t1
WHERE t1.id > (
  SELECT MIN(t2.id) 
  FROM tablename t2 
  WHERE t2.invoice_id = t1.invoice_id AND t2.product_id = t1.product_id
);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=440722cf576de3197127f5f3fd9a69f3).

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to give such a detailed answer. I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an aggregation query:

```
select min(id) as id, invoice_id, product_id,
       sum(quantity) as quantity, sum(total) as total
from t
group by invoice_id, product_id;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I selected the values like this, but how can I update it in the table and delete the old rows as well. edit: I noticed that I forgot to specify this in the question. I have added it now.